# Randomly placing drawables in a grid

Tags: android, drawable

I have a grid layout where the number of rows and columns in it varies depending on the value of an int that is parsed to the activity. I'm now trying to randomly put one of the 12 images I have into each of the grid spaces to get a random mix of images in a square on the screen. So how do I put drawables into grid spaces without using xml and would a table layout be better? I will also need to be able to detect what image is in the grid space when it is clicked on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem while implementing a memory game some time ago.

To get a drawable object you first need to get your app resources.

```
Resources res = getResources();
```

Then, what I do for generate the random position is to put all my images in an ArrayList that has the number of elements equal to the number of grids your have:

```
ArrayList<Drawable> imagesArray = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
imagesArray.add(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.yourdrawablename));
imagesArray.add(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.yourdrawable2name));
//and so on for the following drawables you have.
```

After that, you could generate a random number using your ArrayList's size, that is the same amount of images you have, and after that, you put the images on your grid and remove it from the array.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < imagesArray.size() ; i++) {
    int randomPosition = Random.nextInt(imagesArray.size());
    //here's the code to put your drawable in your grid view, in my case, it was just a button
    //background, so I didn't know exactly how to put it inside a position of the grid, but it
    //should not be that difficult to get it from documentation

    //In my case, I do:

    button.setBackground(imagesArray.get(randomPosition));

    //And then delete that position on the array...

    imagesArray.remove(randomPosition);

    //And repeat until array's length is null;
}
```

For the last question, for discovering witch drawable is in which grid, you could get the constantState of it like this:

```
gridViewElement.getBackground();
```

This will return the background as a drawable that is associated with that gridView.
Also, be aware that if you want to compare to drawables inside two differente grids, you should use this:

```
if(gridViewElement1.getBackground().getConstantState()
    .equals(gridViewElement2.getBackground().getConstantState())) {
    //code goes here.
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use an `ArrayList<Integer>` with the drawable id's and load the drawable later when placing it in an `ImageView`. Also, you could use another `ArrayList` (perhaps 2D?) to store which image is at which location.

Comment: Well, using Integer seems to be a better solution if you need to handle memory problems, awesome suggestion. I'm not familiar with the use of an 2d arrayList, but if it's possible so yes, it's a good solution. In my game, I had to compare 2 elements, and the way I got it working was comparing the constantstate of the element's backgrounds.

Comment: By a 2D array list, I mean `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`. In this case, it will again store drawable ids (or some other identifier). In particular, `list.get(row).get(col)` will return an identifier for the image at cell (row, col).

Comment: I see, didn't know it was possible. Thanks for the tip.